# How much fresh yeast should I use if I want to use it instead of dry yeast?

Tags: baking, yeast

I have a recipe that lists the quantity of dry yeast I need, but I have only fresh yeast.

How much fresh yeast should I use, knowing the quantity of dry yeast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at: http://whatscookingamerica.net/Bread/yeastbreadtip.htm

> **Conversion Measurements for Using Different Yeasts in Recipes:**
>
> ```
> Multiply the amount of instant yeast by 3 for the equivalent amount of fresh yeast.
>
> Multiply the amount of active dry yeast by 2.5 for the equivalent amount of fresh yeast.
>
> Multiply the amount of instant yeast by 1.25 for the equivalent of active dry yeast.
> ```